# How Can I load a picture for a few seconds before running the app?

Tags: ios

I'd like to view a whole screen picture before i load the main view of my app. How is it possible?

Comment: In which method can i do ?

Comment: You have a few options: you can display a splash screen for a few seconds and during this time load the picture, or possibly load the picture in `applicationDidFinishLaunching`. There are a number of methods called before the view actually loads (e.g. `viewWillAppear`), but I don't think there is much need to pre-load the picture at all, as that is a not a memory intensive operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screen you are talking about is known as Splash Screen that gets loaded for a moment before the main view of the applications loads.

Here is a detailed post discussing all aspected of adding a splash screen in your project : [How to Add Splash Screen in Your iOS App](http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/)

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to this one time wherein I wanted to load an animation that combined with the initial splash screen each time the app launched.

The simplest way to handle this ended up being to just to set a viewController with a full screen `UIImageView` as the "Initial View Controller" inside storyboard. I then just set an `NSTimer` to run for the length of the animation (or however long you want to display your other image) and then just segue to your main viewController. Hope it helps!